# Gps,GeoCoding causes app hang in android

Tags: android, gps, location, geocoding, locationlistener

I am using locationListener with Gps.When my Gps symbol gets stable(i.e stop blinking) means it has got the new location ,at that time it hangs my app for a while.I am using locationListener in Service.But when I run "Maps" application(google maps.apk application)  it runs smoothly on Gps.so Whats is the problem whit my app that runs very smoothly if Gps is off.

My Code is here

```
public class LocationUpdateService extends Service implements IActionController{
    private LocationManager _locationManager;
    private String          _provider;
    private boolean         _gpsEnabled;
    private boolean         _networkEnabled;
    private  String         _json;
    private boolean        _locationSendingByCheckIn;
    private Intent         _intent;
    int i=1;

    //private boolean        _locationAvailable;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        i=1;
        String tracking_key = MySharedPreference.getString(MySharedPreference.APP_TRACKING_KEY,"",getApplicationContext());
        if (tracking_key == null || tracking_key.equals("")||!MySharedPreference.getBoolean(MySharedPreference.APP_ALLOWED_TO_POST_LOCATION, false, getApplicationContext()))
        {
            stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LocationUpdateService.class));
        }
        else  
        {
            _locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            setLocationSendingAlarm(AppConstants.PENDING_INTENET_LOCATION_PROVIDER_ENABLE_ALARM_ID);
            getLocation();

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        try {
            if(!MySharedPreference.getBoolean(MySharedPreference.APP_ALLOWED_TO_POST_LOCATION, false, getApplicationContext()))
            {
                stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LocationUpdateService.class));
                return;
            }
            else if (intent.getExtras() != null)
            {


                if (intent.getExtras().getBoolean("locationSendingAlarm"))
                {
                    _locationSendingByCheckIn=false;

                    _gpsEnabled=_locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    _networkEnabled=_locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    String _providerOld=MySharedPreference.getString(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_PROVIDER, "", getApplicationContext());

                    if(_providerOld.equalsIgnoreCase(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)&&_locationManager!=null&&!_gpsEnabled&&_networkEnabled)
                    {
                        _locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                        getLocation();
                        sendLocationOnServer(LocationUpdateService.this,AppConstants.APP_REPORT_TYPE_SOS);
                    }
                    else if((_providerOld.equalsIgnoreCase(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))&&_gpsEnabled)
                    {
                        sendLocationOnServer(LocationUpdateService.this,AppConstants.APP_REPORT_TYPE_SOS);
                        if(_locationManager != null) _locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                        getLocation();
                    }
                    else if(_providerOld.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                    {

                        if(_locationManager != null) _locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                        getLocation();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sendLocationOnServer(LocationUpdateService.this,AppConstants.APP_REPORT_TYPE_SOS);
                    }


                }


                else if(intent.getExtras().getBoolean(AppConstants.APP_REPORT_TYPE_CHECK_IN))
                {
                    _intent=new Intent(AppConstants.CHECK_IN_BROADCAST_RECEIVER);
                    _locationSendingByCheckIn=true;
                    sendLocationOnServer(LocationUpdateService.this,AppConstants.APP_REPORT_TYPE_CHECK_IN);

                }
                else if(intent.getExtras().getBoolean(AppConstants.APP_SETTINGS_CHANGED))
                {
                    setLocationSendingAlarm(AppConstants.PENDING_INTENET_LOCATION_PROVIDER_ENABLE_ALARM_ID);
                    if(_locationManager != null) _locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                    getLocation();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }



    private void getLocation()
    {

                try{

                    _gpsEnabled=_locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    _networkEnabled=_locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


                    /*if(!_gpsEnabled && !_networkEnabled)
            {

            }*/

                    /*Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            _provider = _locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);*/


                    /* Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
              // they would help boost my gps,
                boolean xtraInjection=_locationManager.sendExtraCommand(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                                      "force_xtra_injection",bundle);
                boolean timeInjection=_locationManager.sendExtraCommand(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                                      "force_time_injection",bundle);*/

                    long timeInterval=getTimeInterval();
                    try
                    {
                        if(timeInterval==1000*60)
                            timeInterval=1000*60*2-1000*20; //100 seconds
                        else if(timeInterval==1000*60*5)
                            timeInterval=1000*60*5-1000*30;// 4.5 minutes
                        else timeInterval=1000*60*5-1000*30; //4.5 minutes
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        timeInterval=1000*60*5-1000*30;  //4.5 min
                    }

                    if(_gpsEnabled)
                    {
                        _locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,timeInterval,200,locationListener);
                        return;
                    }
                    else if(_networkEnabled)
                    {
                        _locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,timeInterval,200,locationListener);
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MySharedPreference.putString(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_PROVIDER, "", getApplicationContext());
                    }
                    /*Location location = _locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(null==location)
            {
                location = _locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }
            if(null==location)
            {
                location = _locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

            }
            else if(location != null && location.getProvider()!=null)
            {
                _locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(location.getProvider(),5*60*1000,0,locationListener);
                _locationAvailable=true;

            }*/


                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MySharedPreference.putString(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_PROVIDER, "", getApplicationContext());
                }





    }

    /**
     *
     * Location listener
     */
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            /*
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "status changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                break;
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                break;
            }*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {




        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            i++;
            saveLocation(getApplicationContext(),location);


        }
    };
    public  void saveLocation(Context context, Location location)
    {
        if(location!=null)
        {

            double _latitude=location.getLatitude();
            double _longitude=location.getLongitude();
            double _altidude=location.getAltitude();
            float _accuracy=location.getAccuracy();
            float _bearing=location.getBearing();
            float _speed=location.getSpeed() * 3.6f;
            long _time=location.getTime();
            String _address=getAddress(location);

            double _latitudeOld =MySharedPreference.getFloat(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_LATITUDE, 0.0f, context);
            double _longitudeOld=MySharedPreference.getFloat(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_LONGITUDE, (float)0.0, context);


            MySharedPreference.putBoolean(MySharedPreference.IS_LOCATION_STATIC, _latitude == _latitudeOld && _longitude == _longitudeOld, context);
            MySharedPreference.putFloat(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_LATITUDE, (float)_latitude, context);
            MySharedPreference.putFloat(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_LONGITUDE, (float)_longitude, context);
            MySharedPreference.putFloat(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_ALTITUDE, (float)_altidude, context);
            MySharedPreference.putFloat(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_ACCURACY, _accuracy, context);;;
            MySharedPreference.putFloat(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_BEARING, _bearing, context);;
            MySharedPreference.putFloat(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_SPEED, _speed, context);; ;
            MySharedPreference.putLong(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_TIME, _time, context);
            MySharedPreference.putString(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_ADDRESS, _address, context);
            MySharedPreference.putString(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_PROVIDER, location.getProvider(), context);


            if(NativeHelper.getDistanceInMeter(_latitude, _longitude, _latitudeOld, _longitudeOld) >= 330)
            {
                sendLocationOnServer( LocationUpdateService.this, AppConstants.APP_REPORT_TYPE_SOS);
                setLocationSendingAlarm(AppConstants.PENDING_INTENET_LOCATION_PROVIDER_ENABLE_ALARM_ID);
            }


        }
    }





    public  void sendLocationOnServer(Context context, String reportType)
    {
        try{
            String tracking_key = MySharedPreference.getString(MySharedPreference.APP_TRACKING_KEY,"",context);
            String _providerOld=MySharedPreference.getString(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_PROVIDER, "", context);
            if (tracking_key == null || tracking_key.equals("") ||_providerOld.equals(""))
            {
                return ;
            }

            double _latitudeOld=MySharedPreference.getFloat(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_LATITUDE, 0.0f, context);
            double _longitudeOld=MySharedPreference.getFloat(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_LONGITUDE, (float)0.0, context);
            double _altidudeOld=MySharedPreference.getFloat(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_ALTITUDE, (float)0.0, context);
            float _accuracyOld=MySharedPreference.getFloat(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_ACCURACY, (float)0.0, context);;;
            float _bearingOld=MySharedPreference.getFloat(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_BEARING, (float)0.0, context);;
            float _speedOld=MySharedPreference.getFloat(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_SPEED, (float)0.0, context);; ;

            boolean isStatic = MySharedPreference.getBoolean(MySharedPreference.IS_LOCATION_STATIC, false, context);
            String _addressOld=MySharedPreference.getString(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_LOCATION_ADDRESS, "Address not available", context);

            RequestAppLocationSending appLocationSending=new RequestAppLocationSending();
            appLocationSending.setImei(NativeHelper.getDeviceId(context));
            appLocationSending.setBattery((int)TrackMyDeviceUtils.getBatteryLevel(context));
            appLocationSending.setLatitude(_latitudeOld);
            appLocationSending.setLongitude(_longitudeOld);
            appLocationSending.setAltitude((int)_altidudeOld );
            appLocationSending.setAccuracy(_accuracyOld);
            appLocationSending.setCouse(_bearingOld);
            appLocationSending.setSpeed(_speedOld);
            appLocationSending.setTracking_key(tracking_key);
            appLocationSending.setAddress(_addressOld);
            appLocationSending.setDate(TrackMyDeviceUtils.getFormatedDateForLocationSending());
            appLocationSending.setReportType(reportType);
            appLocationSending.setStatic(isStatic);

            if(_providerOld.equalsIgnoreCase(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                appLocationSending.setData_source("G");
            else
                appLocationSending.setData_source("N");




            _json=  appLocationSending.toJson();

            LocationSendingController locationSendingController=new LocationSendingController((IActionController)context, EventType.APP_LOCATION_SENDING);
            try {
                locationSendingController.requestService(_json);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
    private String getAddress(Location location)
    {
        List<Address>   addresses;
        try{
            addresses = new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault()).getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
            return  findAddress(addresses);


        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            try{
                addresses= ReverseGeocode.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                return  findAddress(addresses);
            }
            catch (Exception e1) {
                return "Address not available";
            }

        }
        //return "Address not available";
    }
    private String findAddress(List<Address>    addresses)
    {
        String address="Address not available";
        if(addresses!=null)
        {

            for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){
                Address addre=addresses.get(i);


                String street=addre.getAddressLine(0);
                if(null==street)
                    street="";

                String city=addre.getLocality();
                if(city==null) city="";
                /*if(city!=null)
                    MySharedPreference.putString(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_CITY_NAME, city, getApplicationContext());
                else
                    city=MySharedPreference.getString(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_CITY_NAME, "", getApplicationContext());*/

                String state=addre.getAdminArea();
                if(state==null) state="";
                /*if(state!=null)
                    MySharedPreference.putString(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_STATE_NAME, state, getApplicationContext());
                else
                    state=MySharedPreference.getString(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_STATE_NAME, "", getApplicationContext());*/

                String country=addre.getCountryName();
                if(country==null) country="";
                /*if(country!=null)
                    MySharedPreference.putString(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_COUNTRY_NAME, country, getApplicationContext());
                else
                    country=MySharedPreference.getString(MySharedPreference.PREVIOUS_COUNTRY_NAME, "", getApplicationContext());*/



                address=street+", "+city+", "+state+", "+country;

            }
            return address;
        }
        return address;
    }
    private void setLocationSendingAlarm(int alarmId) {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationUpdateService.class);
        intent.putExtra("locationSendingAlarm", true);
        PendingIntent   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, AppConstants.PENDING_INTENET_LOCATION_PROVIDER_ENABLE_ALARM_ID, intent,0);
        try {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        long timeForAlarm=getTimeInterval();

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+timeForAlarm, timeForAlarm,pendingIntent);

    }


    private void cancleAlarm(int alarmId)
    {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationUpdateService.class);
        intent.putExtra("locationSendingAlarm", true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, AppConstants.PENDING_INTENET_LOCATION_PROVIDER_ENABLE_ALARM_ID, intent, 0);
        try {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
    @Override
    public Activity getMyActivityReference() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void setScreenData(Object screenData, int event, long time) {

        Message msg=new Message();
        msg.obj=screenData;
        msg.arg1=event;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);

    }

    protected Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            updateUI(msg);
        }
    };


    public void updateUI(Message o)
    {
        try{

            if(o.obj instanceof MyError) {
                switch(((MyError)o.obj).getErrorcode())
                {
                case MyError.NETWORK_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                {
                    if(_locationSendingByCheckIn)
                    {
                        _intent.putExtra("Response","Network not available");
                        _intent.putExtra("LocationPostedSuccessfuly", false);
                        sendBroadcast(_intent);
                        _locationSendingByCheckIn=false;

                    }

                    break;
                }
                case MyError.EXCEPTION:
                case MyError.UNDEFINED:
                {
                    if(_locationSendingByCheckIn)
                    {
                        _intent.putExtra("Response","Server not responding. Please try later");
                        _intent.putExtra("LocationPostedSuccessfuly", false);
                        sendBroadcast(_intent);
                        _locationSendingByCheckIn=false;
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            else if (o.obj instanceof ResponseAppLocationSending) {
                ResponseAppLocationSending responseAppLocationSending=(ResponseAppLocationSending) o.obj;
                if(responseAppLocationSending.getResponce().contains("saved"))
                {

                    if(_locationSendingByCheckIn)
                    {
                        _intent.putExtra("Response","Check In Submitted");
                        _intent.putExtra("LocationPostedSuccessfuly", true);
                        sendBroadcast(_intent);
                    }
                    //else setLocationSendingAlarm(AppConstants.PENDING_INTENET_LOCATION_PROVIDER_ENABLE_ALARM_ID);

                }
                else  {


                    if(_locationSendingByCheckIn)
                    {
                        _intent.putExtra("Response","Server not responding. Please try later");
                        _intent.putExtra("LocationPostedSuccessfuly", false);
                        sendBroadcast(_intent);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if(_locationSendingByCheckIn)
            {
                _intent.putExtra("Response","Server not responding. Please try later");
                _intent.putExtra("LocationPostedSuccessfuly", false);
                sendBroadcast(_intent);
                _locationSendingByCheckIn=false;
            }
        }
        _locationSendingByCheckIn=false;
    }






    private long getTimeInterval()
    {
        try{
            String s=MySharedPreference.getString(MySharedPreference.APP_REPORTING_TIME, "10", getApplicationContext());
            int time = Integer.parseInt(s);
            if(time<1) time=10;

            return  time*1000*60;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return 1000*60*10;  //10 minutes
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        if(_locationManager!=null)
            _locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        cancleAlarm(AppConstants.PENDING_INTENET_LOCATION_PROVIDER_ENABLE_ALARM_ID);
        super.onDestroy();
    }








}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Android development, but most likely your problem would be solved if you do your localization logic within a separate thread.

Comment: until you mention your code . it wont be possible to help much. also if you are posting don't post the whole code. post specific code section that you think can be fishy. only then we can help you better

Comment: @Javanator,npinti, Lucifer   Please check the code

Comment: @npinti You are right.I did the same as you suggest and my problem got solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finaly I got the solution of my problem.I was doing Geo coding frequently but not in a different thread.So I did this(Did Geo coding in a new Thread)

```
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    _address=getAddress(location);
                }
            }).start();

        }
    };
    private String getAddress(Location location)
    {
        List<Address>   addresses;
        try{
            addresses = new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault()).getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
            return  findAddress(addresses);


        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            try{
                addresses= ReverseGeocode.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                return  findAddress(addresses);
            }
            catch (Exception e1) {
                return "Address not available";
            }

        }
        //return "Address not available";
    }
    private String findAddress(List<Address>    addresses)
    {
        String address="Address not available";
        if(addresses!=null)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){
                Address addre=addresses.get(i);
                String street=addre.getAddressLine(0);
                if(null==street)
                    street="";
                String city=addre.getLocality();
                if(city==null) city="";

                String state=addre.getAdminArea();
                if(state==null) state="";

                String country=addre.getCountryName();
                if(country==null) country="";

                address=street+", "+city+", "+state+", "+country;
            }
            return address;
        }
        return address;
    }
    }
```